# EPPLus Finding Cell Value C#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I've had no luck finding resources, though I am looking for help with EPPLus in C#.

All I want to do is be able to check the value of five cells (specific cells) in an Excel spreadsheet, and set them to a variable in my C# program.  Could someone please explain to me how to do this?

Comment: You should really check the documentationsection, there is a link to a nice Getting started tutorial that basically covers all your needs.
Atleast show some effort before someone servs your answer on a silver plate.
However here is the link http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.de/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html

Answer (score -1):

```
var file = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"c:\path\to\excel.xlsx");

using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
     var value = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[0].Cells["A1"].Value;
}
```

As CSharpie said, this is all readily available in the documentation.

Comment: I'm having an error that is:
The type of namespace 'ExcelPackage' could not be found.  Do I have to define it somewhere?

Comment: @user3633690 again that would be in the documentation, very clearly needing a `using OfficeOpenXml;`

Comment: I've added Using OfficeOpenXml; already.  Still returns the same error.  When I remove the code snippet; it compiles fine like I had it originally.

Comment: The error returns:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'CarDashBoard.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '6' and line position '9'.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.